# How to hide TableViewCells?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have 2 arrays.

```
postList:[
    {id: 1, name: "json", content: "hi", sex: "male"},
    {id: 2, name: "bob", content: "hello", sex: "male"},
    {id: 3, name: "john", content: "wow", sex: "male"},
    {id: 3, name: "john", content: "unbelievable", sex: "male"}
    ]

blockList: [
    {id: 3, name: "john"},
    {id: 4, name: "allen"}
]
```

Tableview is made of postList Data.
I want if blockList.id == postList.id, the cell should be hidden.
How to compare 2 arrays and hide cells?

Comment: If hidden you means is not appear in list of tableView. Just making new list match with your condition as data of your tableView

Comment: @bewithyou How can I know they are same?

Comment: Add a third variable that provides the tableview with data, and is derived from the `postList` and `blockList` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hor Compare the array of data and create the result array

Then use the result array to set data to the table view

Refer below:

```
let filteredList = postList.filter { dict in
    !blockList.contains(where: { blockDict in
        return dict["id"] as? Int == blockDict["id"] as? Int
    })
}
    
print(filteredList.map({ $0["name"] as? String }))
```

From above example you can use **filteredArray** to set data to your table view